# How to point Spark temp directory to a different file system in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

In my EMR spark cluster in the core machines I have an EBS volume size of 128GB. My Spark program is giving me "No space left on device" error. So, what I want is in EMR to point the temp directory that spark uses to a different file system "/dev/xvdb2" . How can I do that ?

Below is the output from one of my core machine.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         34G   78k   34G   1% /dev
tmpfs            34G     0   34G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       11G  4.3G  6.1G  42% /
/dev/xvdb1      5.4G   35M  5.4G   1% /emr
/dev/xvdb2      133G   12G  121G   9% /mnt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a job fail with "No space left on device", but df says otherwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707784/why-does-a-job-fail-with-no-space-left-on-device-but-df-says-otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put something similar in your `spark/conf/spark-env.sh`:

> export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/opt/spark/tmp