# How to process multiple pyspark dataframes in parallel

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with millions of records and hundreds of columns (an example below)

```
clm1, clm2, clm3
code1,xyz,123
code2,abc,345
code1,qwe,456
```

I want to do divide it into multiple dataframes based on clm1 i.e. separate dataframe for `clm1=code1` and separate dataframe for `clm1=code2` and so on and then process them and write the result in separate files. I want to perform this operation in parallel to speed up the process. I am using below code:

```
S1 = myclass("code1")
S2 = myclass("code2")


t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=S1.processdata,args=(df,))
t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=S2.processdata,args=(df,))
t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

but i am getting below error

```
Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
```

If I use `threading.Thread` instead of `multiprocessing.Process` it is working fine but  that doesn't seem to reduce the overall time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### About error

> Method **getstate**([]) does not exist

It's a `py4j.Py4JException`. You have this error with `multiprocessing.Process` because this module uses processes. On the other hand
`threading.Thread` uses threads which use the same memory, so they can share the the dataframe object.

Take a also a look in that SO question-answer: [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)

---

#### General advice

I understand that maybe you are new, to Spark world and I suggest you my solution for your problem. You asked how to do multiprocessing, but if you have Spark maybe this is not a best practice.

You have Spark-*a framework for parallel processing*, you don't need to parallelize manually your task.

Spark has designed for parallel computing in a cluster, but it works extremely nice  in a large single node. Multiprocessing library is useful in Python computation tasks, in Spark/Pyspark all the computations run in parallel in JVM.

In python_code.py

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


# JOB 1
df1 = df.filter(f.col('clm1')=='code1')
... many transformations
df1.write.format('..')..

# JOB 2
df2 = df.filter(f.col('clm1')=='code2')
... many transformations
df2.write.format('..')..
```

And then run this code with spark-submit by using all your cores (* = all cores)

```
# Run application locally on all cores
./bin/spark-submit --master local[*] python_code.py
```

With this approach, you use the Spark power.  The jobs will be executed sequentially BUT you will have:
 **CPU utilization all the time** <=> **parallel processing** <=> **lower computation time**

Comment: I am getting below error after 1 hour of processing when it starts writing files
`No space left on device
ERROR TaskMemoryManager: error while calling spill()`

Comment: Ok this ERROR, it's a Linux error. You don't have space in your machine.
You can run 'du -sh' in your bash and see the available space. Also this, error is independent with the question. The answer was about the design, this error and maybe other errors that will maybe occur are implementation details, that will answer in different questions if they are not exist in Stackoverflow

Comment: @user0204 about the design, are you ok? have understand the concept behind Pyspark (Spark in general)?

Comment: but i am writing files on s3 with unlimited space and not on the the same machine on which i am running my script, then why i am receiving this error? I understood the concept but I had to try this before accepting your answer.

Comment: @user0204 you have right I didn't explain why you have this error :-) Because it was not a best practice in I target my answer in Spark. Now I updated my answer about your error.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Now can you please tell me why I am getting no disk left in space on linux? as I am not writing files on linux I am writing files on s3 which has unlimited space. Sorry if that question sounds dumb but I am trying to understand it.

Comment: @user0204 Take a look on that question, is the same with your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707784/why-does-a-job-fail-with-no-space-left-on-device-but-df-says-otherwise

Comment: I tried running your solution on a small dataset but it seems to be running sequentially. seconds started when first finished,

Comment: You can make other question with this problem, because it's a different case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207253/discussion-between-user0204-and-ggeop).